# yii datetimepicker showing wrong time

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii app with a view that shows details from a database, when the user clicks the Update button, it opens a form with the same details in for editing. However the datetime field is different on the view, the time is correct, on the form the time is an hour behind.  The code on the view is:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'date_time',
    'format' => ['date', 'php:d-M-Y H:i']
],
```

this shows the correct date and time

in the form, the code is

```
echo $form->field($model, 'date_time')->widget(\kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker::className(), [
    'convertFormat' => true,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i'
    ],
]);
```

this shows the time as 1 hour behind

in the config/main.php file the timezone is set to

```
'timeZone' => 'Europe/London'
```

I've been messing about with this all day and I just can't work it out, would appreciate some pointers

I've just tried adding these lines:

```
$this_date = $formatter->astime($model->date_time);
echo $this_date
```

and this gives the correct date and time but if I then change the field to

```
echo $form->field($model, $this_date)->widget(\kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker::className(), [
    'convertFormat' => true,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i'
    ],
]);
```

I get an error saying "Attribute name must contain word characters only."

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're trying to access a model attribute with the date that you formatted. Use the value attribute instead

```
    echo $form->field($model, 'date_time') >widget(\kartik\widgets\DateTimePicker::className(), [
    'convertFormat' => true,
    'value'=> $this_date,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i'
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

sorted it, changed the field to

```
echo 'Incident Date/Time'; 
echo DatePicker::widget([
       'name' => 'date_time',
       'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_PREPEND,
       'value' => $this_date,
       'pluginOptions' => [
         'autoclose'=>true
       ] 
     ]);
```

and now its showing the correct date and time